# C++ - Move application out of screen

Tags: c++

So I want to create a c++ application that would come out from out of the screen when a button (that is visible on screen) is clicked and then the opposite.

How can I achieve this?

edit: i'm planning to do this on windows (winapi)

Comment: What operating system? The C++ language doesn't have the concept of a "screen" or a "button".

Comment: You will have to look up that functionality in the documentation of whatever GUI library or framework you are using.  There is no GUI defined in the C++ language.

Comment: Do you mean changing the foreground window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use ::MoveWindow (or ::SetWindowPos) to change the position of the main window on a timer (WM_TIMER) callback.

Comment: that would work i guess, thanks